# Running a command on all servers using Fabric

Tags: linux, python, configuration

I am not sure , whether i should i ask this question here or some other stack-exchange community  , but i am trying some simple commands to run on a list of servers , using python fabric.

The code for the command:

```
    from fabric.api import run
    def host_type():
      run('uname -s')
```

This will run the `uname -s` command on all Linux servers by invoking:

```
  $fab -H < ......Comma, separated , Servers , List , Here.....> host_type
```

Now the problem is that , how can i run it/configure it such that it returns the results without asking for user/root password during execution. There might be some Linux command line trick but i don't remember.

**Edit1:**

Ok there is a -p option with fab command but each server has a different password, so this option may not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that you can do that. `Fabric` uses `openssh` on the backend so if you already configured passwordless connection then you will not need to set anything and it will work.

The other way is simple as well. You only need to set up the `env` variables.

```
from fabric.state import env

env.user = "user"
env.password = "password"

env.colorize_errors = True
env.connection_attempts = 3
env.disable_known_hosts = True
env.skip_bad_hosts = True
env.parallel = False
env.linewise = True
```

This should do the trick. I usually put it in a separate file and import it.

PS: I, personally, find `paramiko` which is the library that `Fabric` uses is easier to use for simpler tasks.

Comment: Hi , thanks. This assumes that each server has the same user-name and password?

Comment: @IjazKhan that is correct. If they don't then you will have to set it per server basis before you run the connection string.

Comment: Cant i use a file as input to fab , that read credentials for each one separately?

Comment: @IjazKhan I don't see why not. You can actually make it easier on yourself and import a python file that has a `dict` variable with all the information you need.